# How to import & export product attributes in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, importexport

I have created product attributes in  my magento site,now i want to export all  attributes to another magento site. 
Please suggest how it can be done?

Comment: i recommend https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/import-export-product-attributes-by-magerips.html this extension their are some more extensions also have a look on that.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not exist in Magento. One of the best extensions out there for this: http://www.commerceextensions.com/magento-import-export-bulk-product-attributes.html